# How to Multi-Filter an Array in Javascript with multiple Conditions from Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

Greeting, I'm trying to filter an array of products based on multiple conditions from an object and i can't get my head around it. Can someone send me in the right direction?

**Conditions (Object)**

```
const Conditionobject = {
Brand: ["msi", "acer"]
Processor: ["intel i7", "intel i9"]
Refreshrate: ["165 hz"]
}
```

**Products (Array)**

```
const AllProducts= [ 
{
Productname: Acer Nitro,
Specifications: { Brand: "acer", Processor: "intel i7", Refreshrate: "144 hz"}
},
{
Productname: Msi Katana,
Specifications: { Brand: "msi", Processor: "intel i7", Refreshrate: "165 hz"}
},
{
Productname: Acer Aspire,
Specifications: { Brand: "acer", Processor: "intel i9", Refreshrate: "165 hz"}
},
]
```

**Final: Filtered Array Products**

The final filtered array of products should contain the objects with the productnames **Msi Katana** & **Acer Aspire,** based on the given conditions. Can someone explain me how to achieve this?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate all conditions and filter the products.

```js
const
    conditions = { Brand: ["msi", "acer"], Processor: ["intel i7", "intel i9"], Refreshrate: ["165 hz"] },
    products = [{ Productname: "Acer Nitro", Specifications: { Brand: "acer", Processor: "intel i7", Refreshrate: "144 hz" } }, { Productname: "Msi Katana", Specifications: { Brand: "msi", Processor: "intel i7", Refreshrate: "165 hz" } }, { Productname: "Acer Aspire", Specifications: { Brand: "acer", Processor: "intel i9", Refreshrate: "165 hz" } }],
    result = products.filter(product => Object
        .entries(conditions)
        .every(([key, values]) => values.includes(product.Specifications[key]))
    )
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This should work! Thanks for the quick response Nina!

Comment: Dude consider upvoting if the answer helps or guides you, these guys will become more inclined to help, Cheers

Comment: Relax, I can't vote yet...